# CMake is dropping a preprocessor definition

Tags: c++, c, cmake

#### cmake --build _build output

> WARNING: Preprocessor definitions containing '#' may not be passed on
>   the compiler command line because many compilers do not support it.
>   ***CMake is dropping a preprocessor definition:*** BUILD_HOST="Linux
>   cvuppala-bri-vm 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 22 22:00:00
>   UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux" Consider defining the macro
>   in a (configured) header file.

#### Get host

*corresponding code cmake code snippet*

```
execute_process(
  COMMAND uname -a
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE BUILD_HOST
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
  )

add_definitions(-DBUILD_HOST="${BUILD_HOST}")
```

Comment: A good idea if possible would be to do as cmake suggests. Use configure_file() to configure a config.hpp header file and include that in your project's public header files

Comment: Another way s to use configure_file to build a response file for the compiler and specify the response file in the compiler options property for the target.

Comment: @RichardHodges yes that is better if you are starting from scratch, but we are now upgrading to cmake from make, i cannot change source files.

Comment: you mean you are downgrading....

Comment: @RichardHodges i did not get you?

Comment: sorry, i misread your comment. I thought you were upgrading the other way. In this case you'll want to use the response file route. all compilers I know of allow the use of `@options.rsp` where `options.rsp` is the path to a file containing options to apply.
YOu can generate this file in cmake and then add it to the COMPILE_OPTIONS property of the target. Don't forget to use the APPEND option when adding to the COMPILE_OPTIONS property.

Comment: OK, answer posted.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the output of command `uname -a` contains '#'. Even though the string is quoted, I wonder why cmake forbids it.

However, to solve this problem, you should remove '#' or replace '#' to another character from `BUILD_HOST` before adding definition.

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "\#"
       "" BUILD_HOST
       ${BUILD_HOST})
```

This would **remove** '#' from your `BUILD_HOST` string.

If you want to perform replacing rather than removing, try something like following:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "\#"
           "$" BUILD_HOST
           ${BUILD_HOST})
```

This would **replace** '#' to '$'.

---

**EDIT:**

I think it is impossible to add definition which contains '#' via `add_definitions`. But, if you have to pass result as-is, you can add compile options manually.

```
set(EXTRA_COMPILE_OPTIONS -DBUILD_HOST="${BUILD_HOST}")
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${EXTRA_COMPILE_OPTIONS})
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, Is there any alternate way i can pass uname -a result as it is?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use a response file to set extra command line options for the compiler:

#### step 1:

create the response file template, in this case called `extra_options.rsp.in`

```
-DBUILD_HOST="@RESULT_OF_UNAME@"
```

#### step 2:

configure this file in the cmakelists.txt file:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "uname" "-a" 
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE RESULT_OF_UNAME
                OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
configure_file(extra_options.rsp.in
               ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/extra_options.rsp 
               @ONLY)
```

#### step 3:

add a reference to the configured response file to the compiled options:
(in this case, my target is called `algo`)

```
set_property(TARGET algo APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS
             "@${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/extra_options.rsp")
```

Example output on my system:

#### extra_options.rsp:

```
-DBUILD_HOST="Darwin codeblaster.local 16.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
```

result of `VERBOSE=1 make`:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++

  -isystem 
  /Users/rhodges/.hunter/_Base/3973bc2/7c86f54/a5fd140/Install/include
  -g
  @/Users/rhodges/algo/cmake-build-debug/extra_options.rsp 
  -std=gnu++14 
  -o CMakeFiles/algo.dir/main.cpp.o 
  -c /Users/rhodges/algo/main.cpp`